# How to develop Nexus 3 repository plugin?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

In my team, we want to create our own Nexus plugin (for Nexus 3) to prevent or allow some packages to be downloaded based on our own custom rules.

I know about such a solution as Nexus Firewall, but we can not use it, since it is not free.

I have tried to find documentation or a guide on how to make your own plugin but was not able to find any decent resources.

Links I found:

- [Nexus development guide](https://sonatype-nexus-community.github.io/nexus-development-guides/) (To be honest not that good guide)
- The same [question](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465848-How-do-I-extend-Nexus-or-write-a-plugin-) to sonotype team (but about nexus2)
- [Snyk plugin](https://github.com/snyk/nexus-snyk-security-plugin) - great example but no way a strict documentation

It would be really helpful if anyone can give any advice on where to start first or provide any helpful links to use.